# How to realize Hexadecimal long division in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, hex, calculator

I wanna realize the calculator, the calc should be working with 2,8,10,16 notation.
I already did: **add**, **sub**, **mul**, but i don't understand completely how to realize **div** for 16 notation. And yes I'm new in Python.
How to realize Hexadecimal long division for my class Calculator?

My code:

```
numbers = {'0': '0', '1': '1', '2': '2', '3': '3', '4': '4', '5': '5', '6': '6', '7': '7', '8': '8', '9': '9',
       'A': '10', 'B': '11', 'C': '12', 'D': '13', 'E': '14', 'F': '15', '-': '-'}

rev_numbers = {'0': '0', '1': '1', '2': '2', '3': '3', '4': '4', '5': '5', '6': '6', '7': '7', '8': '8', '9': '9',
           '10': 'A', '11': 'B', '12': 'C', '13': 'D', '14': 'E', '15': 'F', '-': '-'}


class Calculator:


def __init__(self, num, num2, system):
    self.result = []
    self.shift = 0  
    self.system = system  

def __add__(self, l1, l2):
    self.result = []
    max_len = max(len(l1), len(l2))
    l1, l2 = l1.rjust(max_len, '0'), l2.rjust(max_len, '0')
    if self.system == 16:
        l1 = [numbers[value] for value in l1 if
              value in numbers.keys()]  
        l2 = [numbers[value] for value in l2 if value in numbers.keys()]
    for i in range(max_len - 1, -1, -1):
        r = int(l1[i]) + int(l2[i]) + self.shift
        self.shift = r // self.system
        r = r % self.system
        self.result.append(str(r))

    if self.shift > 0:
        self.result.append(str(self.shift))

    r = [rev_numbers[value] for value in self.result if
         value in rev_numbers.keys()]  

    self.shift = 0

    return ''.join(r)[::-1]

def __sub__(self, l1, l2):
    char = ''
    if len(l1) < len(l2):
        l1, l2 = l2, l1
        char = '-'
    max_len = max(len(l1), len(l2))
    l1, l2 = l1.rjust(max_len, '0'), l2.rjust(max_len, '0')
    if self.system == 16:
        l1 = [numbers[value] for value in l1 if value in numbers.keys()]
        l2 = [numbers[value] for value in l2 if value in numbers.keys()]
    for i in range(max_len - 1, -1, -1):
        r = int(l1[i]) - int(l2[i]) - self.shift
        if r >= 0:
            self.result.append(str(r))
            self.shift = 0
        else:
            r += self.system
            self.shift = 1
            self.result.append(str(r))

    if char == '-':
        self.result.append(char)

    r = [rev_numbers[value] for value in self.result if value in rev_numbers.keys()]

    self.result = []

    r = ''.join(r)[::-1]

    return r.lstrip('0')
```

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.
"I don't know how to do it" is not a Stack Overflow issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any base first:

1. **implement a shift left `<<` and right `>>` arithmetic by digit**

   on strings is this easy just copy the array one character to the left or right and insert zero from the other side. In case of signed base's complement numbers for shift right you copy most significant digit so zero for positive and for negative its `base-1`. That way the number will still be signed...

   This operation is also multiplication/division by base.

   ```
   A*Base = A<<1
   A/Base = A>>1

   A*Base*Base = A<<2
   A*Base*Base*Base = A<<3
   ...
   ```
2. **implement substraction of two numbers**

   you claim that you already have this...
3. **implement comparison of two numbers**

   This is the same as substraction but instead of returning result return just if the substraction overflowed or zeroed or not... That will tell you if the numbers are ==, < or >. I usually encode the result into

   ```
   -1 A<B
    0 A==B
   +1 A>B
   ```

**Now long division**

```cpp
C = A/B // division
D = A%B // remainder
```

I do not code in python but in pseudo code for unsigned integers it would be like this:

```cpp
C=0;  // division
D=A;  // remainder
q=1;  // actual weight of B

if (B==0) handle division by zero !!!

while (A>=B) // shift B so its biggest and still smaller or equal to A
 {
 B=B<<1;  
 q=q<<1;
 }
if (q>1)
 {
 B=B>>1;
 q=q>>1;
 }

for (;q>0;) // long division
 {
 while (D>=B)
  {
  D=D-B;
  C=C+q;
  }
 B=B>>1;    // shift right by one digit
 q=q>>1;
 }
```

For signed numbers you can extract sign of the result first and then divide abs values.

For decimals you need to add decimal point and end the division when hitting the same remainder as before, or max fractional digit count is hit. You would also need to slightly change the initial shift of B as it can be mach bigger then A from start so thee would be another while added that shift it right.

All of this is doable on strings so you do not need to convert to ints and back like you do now which is susceptible to integer limits hence limiting the size of numbers used ...

As you can see long division is very similar to shift and add multiplication (just shift in opposite direction and substract instead of add)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand what your desired action is. But as long as you want to divide long numbers in python you can see my answer below.

```
# Python3 program to implement division  
# with large number  
import math 

# A function to perform division of  
# large numbers  
def longDivision(number, divisor):  

    # As result can be very large  
    # store it in string  
    ans = "";  

    # Find prefix of number that  
    # is larger than divisor.  
    idx = 0;  
    temp = ord(number[idx]) - ord('0'); 
    while (temp < divisor): 
        temp = (temp * 10 + ord(number[idx + 1]) -
                            ord('0')); 
        idx += 1; 

    idx +=1; 

    # Repeatedly divide divisor with temp.  
    # After every division, update temp to  
    # include one more digit.  
    while ((len(number)) > idx):  

        # Store result in answer i.e. temp / divisor  
        ans += chr(math.floor(temp // divisor) + ord('0'));  

        # Take next digit of number 
        temp = ((temp % divisor) * 10 + ord(number[idx]) -
                                        ord('0')); 
        idx += 1; 

    ans += chr(math.floor(temp // divisor) + ord('0')); 

    # If divisor is greater than number  
    if (len(ans) == 0):  
        return "0";  

    # else return ans  
    return ans;  

# Driver Code 
number = "1248163264128256512";  
divisor = 125;  
print(longDivision(number, divisor));  

# This code is contributed by mits
```